# How to work with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

A have programmed in Java (Android, PC) and iOS and I am starting to program in C# WFP.
My question is if In Android for each new view I have activities, at Java swing I have card panel, in iOS I have story board with different classes for each view. How does it work in C#? What is the right way to navigate between classes with views. What term should I search to find the right tutorial for this, can you please point me at the right direction.

Comment: Not sure but `Presenter` or `View-Model` may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider the following:

1. Use the [MVVM design pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)
2. Use an [MVVM framework](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/UsingTheMVVMPatternRequiresAFramework.aspx) (e.g. [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/))
3. Use the view model first approach

In this case, you create instances of your view models, and the views are located and displayed which correspond to the view model.

The UI elements on the views (e.g. `Button`) invoke verbs (methods) on your view models. Properties exposed on your view models are *bound* to the UI elements so that changes either side are reflected on the other.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem a while ago.
I used [Matthew MacDonald's Pro WPF with C# 2010](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430272058), the book was really good, as it has lots of really good examples.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look over here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx

There will explain what is WPF and how to use.

Take a look also over: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx